# How to use JSON variables in an Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm not sure if this is possible as I've searched but couldn't find anything related, but didn't find anything saying it's not!

In my Azure DevOps build pipeline I have a variable which holds a JSON value e.g:

[image]

Is there anyway of using a value of a json variable within a task? I've tried (on the off chance) `$(myJson.message)` and `$(myJson).message` but these didn't work.

So do pipeline variables only support simple types? Or is there a way round this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Do you mean get a task to transform a file that contains a json variable? Also, what's the task you're using and what's the goal?

Comment: Have you considered already using a powershell task to parse the variable and using a [command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md#task-logging-commands) to set a variable for use later in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use something like powershell's `Convert-FromJson` to create a json object, but there's no way to tell a random task "treat this variable value as an object, rather than a raw string". You'll have to parse it yourself.