# How to pass Json variable to command line task in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am populating a pipeline variable in Powershell task and it is getting populated successfully:

```
    $env:RESULTJSON=$json
Write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testJSON]$json"
```

However, when I try to use it to pass the value in a command line task I am not able to do so:

```
    task: CmdLine@2 
    env:     
      InputJSON: $(testJSON)    
    inputs:      
    script:
        echo %INPUTJSON%        
        'jsonProcessor.exe $(Build.BuildID),%INPUTJSON%'    
    workingDirectory: './jsonProcExe/'
```

I am getting just "{" in testJSON instead of the whole JSON value.

Comment: Does this help? https://medium.com/microsoftazure/how-to-pass-variables-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-tasks-5c81c5d31763

Comment: What is `resultJSON`? where is coming from?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? That should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to get the value of resultJson.

1.If the `resultJson` is the [pipeline variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline), you should use `InputJSON: $(resultJSON)` instead of `InputJSON: $($resultJSON)`.

Assuming the value of pipeline variable `resultJSON` is 100, then all the tasks within the pipeline can get its value 100. You can modify its value in `Task` scope using `$env:RESULTJSON=$json`, then the value of this variable would be the value of `$json` in that PS task.

But note: Other tasks would get 100 instead of value of `$json`. (Distinguish the difference between Pipeline Scope and Task Scope)

2.If the `resultJson` is a variable defined in PS task, then other tasks can't access its value cause the variable is **only valid in current session**. (You can add second PS task to test it)

To define a variable across multiple tasks/steps, you can use [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell) in PS task, check [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)
.

### Update 1

The logging command doesn't support Json format variable directly. So we need to convert it into one line before defining the variable:

```
$json=$json| ConvertTo-Json -Compress
Write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testJSON]$json"
```

### Update 2

Another direction is to pass the json data via a file. For example first PS task uses `$JSON | Out-File Test.json` to output the content into Test.json file. And the next PS task uses `$Input = Get-Content Test.json` and `Write-Host $Input` to display the value. Also, the second task could be cmd task, their(PS task, CMD task) default working directories are the same one.

Comment: I have changed the question in accordance to your answer, I am still stuck, can you please help?

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty Hmm, so your variable is not normal string variable, instead it's one JSON data variable?  Try using `ConvertTo-Json -Compress` to convert it first before setting variable.

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty Azure devops service doesn't support defining and passing json variable directly, you have to convert the json data to pass the variable. Or share the content of json variable via files. See similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460959/how-to-use-json-variables-in-an-azure-devops-pipeline). Update with update2.

Comment: your first edit worked. json has to be compressed and then passed, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help :)